# Passing each value from a temp table to a scalar function and sum values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am relativity newbie in SQL so please do not  judge strictly. I have a table valued function.Within that function I have a this code:

```
 DECLARE @totalPayment DECIMAL(18,4),
         @totalPaymentConverted DECIMAL(18,4),
         @fromCurrencyIdForPaymentSystemsId CHAR(3);

 DECLARE @GetTotalPaymentAmount AS TABLE 
 (
   Amount     DECIMAL(18,4),
   CurrencyId CHAR(3)
 );

INSERT INTO @GetTotalPaymentAmount
  SELECT    SUM(Amount),CurrencyId
  FROM      [dbo].[fn_DepositWithdrawReport]()
  WHERE     OperationTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY  CurrencyId;
```

This insert return met table like this

```
 A      C
-----|------
550  | USD
650  | EU
     |
```

I want to pass each of this values Amount and CurrencyId to the Scalar valued Function as Input parameter like this:

```
[dbo].[function_Valued](@totalPayment,@fromCurencyId,@toCurrencyId)
```

And sum that values for instance if we consider the table above:

```
[dbo].[functin_scalar](550, USD, EU) = 450
[dbo].[function_scalar](650, EU, EU) = 650
```

Get total 1100

Put simply I want to calculate sum amount and I need to convert it in one currency. I have been told to use APPLY but I cannot understand how to use it in my code. Maybe someone could show in code example?

Comment: Could you add [function_scalar] code? Maybe you can use an INLINE UDF instead of a scalar function o some user can show you how to use an APPLY solution.

Comment: And please tag your SQL Server version.

Comment: I could show bu t i am sure that i cannot  change the code of that function in our system it is used literally everywhere.It is scalar valued function with decimal return type

Comment: I did some test passing a list of int't to an inline UDF and there is a way if you 're interested.

Comment: Yeah sure .Bu i've deleted the post.

Comment: Lunch time now, if you reopen the question I'll post an answer, but only for the SQL part, can you use TYPE with entity framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward with scalar functions, although your description is very confusing and hard to follow with regard to function names and parameter names. Anyway, when you have a scalar function and a table of values that you want to pass as arguments to the function one row at a time, you can go like this:

```
SELECT
  dbo.function_scalar(Amount, CurrencyId, 'EU')
FROM
  @GetTotalPaymentAmount
;
```

That will give you a column of values each of which is the result for a corresponding row of the table. At this point you can specify `Amount` and `CurrencyId` to return them along with the results to verify the results match the input values.

Now, as I have understood from your description, the results will be amounts in the same currency. You can get the total amount by aggregating the column returned by the function, for which you simply need to apply `SUM()` to the function result:

```
SELECT
  SUM(dbo.function_scalar(Amount, CurrencyId, 'EU'))
FROM
  @GetTotalPaymentAmount
;
```

That is basically it. If you need to return the result as a single-row single-column dataset or otherwise use it as a derived table in another query, you will probably want to assign an alias to the aggregated column by changing the `SUM` line to this:

```
  TotalAmount = SUM(...)
```

or this:

```
  SUM(...) AS TotalAmount
```

You can also just store the result in a variable if necessary:

```
  @TotalAmount = SUM(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE payments (Amount DECIMAL(18,4), CurrencyId CHAR(3));
> CREATE TABLE change (FromCurrency VARCHAR(10), ToCurrency VARCHAR(10), Factor DECIMAL(18,4));
> INSERT INTO payments VALUES (550.0, 'USD'), (650, 'EU');
> INSERT INTO change VALUES('USD', 'EU', 0.8040), ('EU', 'EU', 1.0);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM payments;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Amount   | CurrencyId
> :------- | :---------
> 550.0000 | USD       
> 650.0000 | EU
> ```

Just to show you how could implement an [APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) solution. The APPLY part will be executed for every record of payments table. In this case I've not used any UDF.

> ```
> SELECT      p.Amount, p.CurrencyID, c.Factor,
>             p.Amount * COALESCE(c.Factor, 0) AS AmountEU,
>             SUM(p.Amount * COALESCE(c.Factor, 0)) 
>                 OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) Total
> FROM        payments p
> OUTER APPLY (SELECT Factor
>              FROM   change
>              WHERE  FromCurrency = p.CurrencyID
>              AND    ToCurrency = 'EU') c;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Amount   | CurrencyID | Factor | AmountEU     | Total        
> :------- | :--------- | :----- | :----------- | :------------
> 550.0000 | USD        | 0.8040 | 442.20000000 | 442.20000000 
> 650.0000 | EU         | 1.0000 | 650.00000000 | 1092.20000000
> ```

Then if you have a scalar UDF function similar to this:

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION getCurrency(@Amount DECIMAL(18,4), @FromC VARCHAR(10), @ToC VARCHAR(10))
> RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
> AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @Value DECIMAL(18,4);
>
>     SELECT @Value = Factor
>     FROM   change
>     WHERE  FromCurrency = @FromC
>     AND    ToCurrency = @ToC;
>
>     RETURN COALESCE(@Value, 0) * @Amount;
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

In this case you don't need an APPLY solution, you can use your function directly in your code in this way.

Notice in both queries I've added a cumulative total using a [Window Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql).

> ```
> SELECT      p.Amount, p.CurrencyID,
>             dbo.getCurrency(p.Amount, p.CurrencyID, 'EU') AS AmountEU,
>             SUM(dbo.getCurrency(p.Amount, p.CurrencyID, 'EU')) 
>                 OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) Total
> FROM        payments p
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Amount   | CurrencyID | AmountEU | Total    
> :------- | :--------- | :------- | :--------
> 550.0000 | USD        | 442.2000 | 442.2000 
> 650.0000 | EU         | 650.0000 | 1092.2000
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b95503c011e625b67508f1a8c96d97e1)*